# XSL - how to next for each loop inside another for each to link the same values from different xml nodes

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm struggling to create an excel with xslt that will link (join) the two nodes on the same level by common attribute value.

Here goes the input xml:

````
```
<Nodes>
<Item name="ABC" category_id="A"></Item>
<Item name="DEF" category_id="B"></Item>
<Category name="First category" cat_id="A"</Category>
<Category name="Second category" cat_id="B"</Category>
</Nodes>```
````

And part of an xsl:

```
        <xsl:for-each select="//tc:Nodes/tc:Item">
             <xsl:variable name="item_name" select="./@Name" />
             <xsl:variable name="item_category_id" select="./@category_id" />
             <xsl:for-each select="//tc:Nodes:tc:Category/@cat_id = $category_id">
               <xsl:variable name="category_category_id" select="./@cat_id />
             </xsl:for-each>
             <xsl:call-template name="generateReportData">
               <xsl:with-param name="item_name" select="$item_name"/>
               <xsl:with-param name="item_category_id" select="$item_category_id" />
               **<xsl:with-param name="category_category_id" select="$category_category_id"/>**
             </xsl:call-template>

         </xsl:for-each>
```

The problem is that I cannot access the variable **$category_category_id** as it says it is either not defined or out of scope.

The result should one row containing values like: ABC, A, First category (it will link the values from two nodes by common category ID). Please, help -i'm newbie to xsl - maybe there is another way to do so.

Regards, Luke

Answer (score 1):

> link (join) the two nodes on the same level by common attribute value.

This is best done using a **[key](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#key)**. For example:

**XML**

```
<Nodes>
    <Item name="ABC" category_id="A"/>
    <Item name="DEF" category_id="B"/>
    <Category name="First category" cat_id="A"/>
    <Category name="Second category" cat_id="B"/>
</Nodes>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="cat" match="Category" use="@cat_id" />

<xsl:template match="Nodes">
    <Table>
        <xsl:for-each select="Item">
            <Row>
                <Cell>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@name"/>
                </Cell>
                <Cell>
                    <xsl:value-of select="key('cat', @category_id)/@name"/>
                </Cell>
            </Row>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Table>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Table>
  <Row>
    <Cell>ABC</Cell>
    <Cell>First category</Cell>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Cell>DEF</Cell>
    <Cell>Second category</Cell>
  </Row>
</Table>
```

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks, is it possible that this xsl:key element is not supported? I get such message that it is not supported in the namespace xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform".

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio, if you can advice something better to do it, then please tell :)

Comment: No, I don't believe it's possible.

Comment: @Lukasz - What version of Visual Studio do you use? There should really be no problem using `xsl:key` in that. Strictly speaking, Visual Studio isn't an XSLT processor itself, but (probably) uses MSXML.dll behind the scenes. Perhaps it is using a really old version of that. (See https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/278674/determine-the-version-of-msxml-parser-installed-on-a-computer)

Comment: @TimC - thanks, do not worry, I have overcome that problem - it is new version of a Visual Studio. However i still struggle. On the sample data here the solution works. but I cannot still make it on the real data - I get XML document must contain a root level element - i try to access: <xsl:key name="child_item" match="//tcplm:TCXML/tcplm:PSOccurrence" use="@child_item"/> but it looks like it cannot fetch this path and build output.

Comment: @Lukasz The error message indicates a problem with your input XML, not with your XSLT.. -- P.S. The `match` attribute of  a key is a *pattern*, not a path. Starting a pattern with `//` does not accomplish anything.

Comment: @Michael Input is correct - i am able to iterate it with xsl:for-each and I'm getting the desired result. It must be something with the schema headers.

Comment: @Lukasz This is not going anywhere. Either edit your question and show a representative example of your input, or start a new question.